# Problem Calling method inside a dll from another dll in VC++

Tags: visual-c++

I am trying to Build a win DLL in Vc++ smart project for mobile application 5.0 using c#

In my DLL a method called from  another DLL.

I make the following settings in the dll project :

Tools ->options -> vc++ Directories

platform->windows mobile 5.0 sdk 
set the corresponding include and lib path.

Set the lib file as follows :
project properties -> linker -> input -> additional dependencies

provide the additional include directories in the project properties -> C/C++ -> General

In the dll project i export the function declaration in the .h file in the following way :

__declspec (dllexport)  int __cdecl CloseBTStack(void);

this type of error comes at build time for that called method..

Error   1   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) int __cdecl GAP_Query_Local_BD_ADDR(unsigned int,struct _tagBD_ADDR_t *)" (_*imp*?GAP_Query_Local_BD_ADDR@@YAHIPAU_tagBD_ADDR_t@@@Z) referenced in function "int __cdecl OpenBTStack(void)" (?OpenBTStack@@YAHXZ)  SDPDll.obj  SDPDll

plz help me...

Answer (score 0):

In the .h file, write

extern "C"
{

## include "createdll.dll"

}

Then it execute fine.........